# Run Zend from Terminal OSX

Tags: php, macos, zend-framework, terminal

I'm a PHP developer with little knowledge of bash commands and general use of Terminal in OSX.  I'm also new to the Zend Framework and I'm trying to set up my environment and I just can't get started.

The information i've found on the net after a few weeks of research is either incomplete or assumes expert knowledge of Terminal.

My instructions were to install Zend Community Server, once this was done I was instructed to add the /bin and /lib to my "PATH".  Firstly, there seem to be two /bin folders and one /library, not a /lib.  Also, I can't seem to execute commands on the root...even when using sudo and entering my password, no dice.  I read that I could edit the bash profile for my user account (Even though I was under the impression that I was already SU), but even after entering my pw, still no dice.  This is what I have in my .bashrc file in ~/

`PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/zend/lib`

After installing the Community Server I was under the impression that I should be able to run commands from Terminal as I've done from Command Line on Windows 7, but I still get "'zf' command not found"

I've been to a tutorial by IBM, i've gone through the Quick Start on Zend's site and I've gone through a very popular PDF download tutorial by (i think) Rob Allen, and either I'm just lame, or the instructions just don't seem to cover some of the issues I'm having.  If anyone here can help me with some sort of step by step, or even just help me troubleshoot to find out what I've done wrong...that would really be appreciated.

I have to get Zend going before moving to much further ahead with any more development...but man, why is it so difficulty just to get doing?  Anyway, thanks for any help. You guys have always been pretty prompt and thorough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by adding an alias for *zf* to my *.bash_profile*.

Try this in your terminal:

```
echo 'alias zf=/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/bin/zf.sh' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you can run *zend tool* from anywhere by typing **zf** in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your terminal:

echo 'alias zf=/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/bin/zf.sh' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
Now you can run zend tool from anywhere by typing zf in your terminal.